# GlobalInterfacePointer passing using AfxBeginthread

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, com, marshalling

I am using a worker thread inside a CDialog class.

```
 theApp.m_pWorkerThread = AfxBeginThread(Threadproc,this);
```

Now I need to pass a global Inerface poiner to the worker thread so as to access a COM object from outside

Can someone tell me the syntax to pass the GIT cookie and access it inside the thread.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I will answer this myself

This can be done in 3 ways actually. one way I will brief.

using the CComGitPtr from atlbase.h

Do like this :

> CComGitPtr
>   GitPtrName (pointer to the initialized
>   interface)

Now extract the cookie from the DWORD dwCokie = GitPtrName->Detach();

Now pass the cookie as a content of struct(optional) inside the worker thread.

Once you are inside the worker thread, extract the cookie, call CoInitilize, and instantiate the reqiuired interface pointer.

as COMInterfacethatneedMarshalling pReqd.

Now pass the git cookie to the GI table and retrieve the marshalled COM object.

like:

> ```
>     // This is done inide the thread
>     // retrieve the passed cookie as dwCookie
>     CComGITPtr<COMInterfacethatneedMarshalling
> ```
>
> pToGITTest(dwCookie);
>           COMInterfacethatneedMarshalling pReqd;
>           pToGITTest.CopyTo(&pReqd);

```
   Now we have pToGITTest inside the thread, fully marshalled, go ahead and enjoy!
```

Thanks.